# How do I build this SUBQUERY NSPredicate?

Tags: objective-c, ios, core-data, subquery, nspredicate

the problem is this:

I have 3 Entities: ImgThumb, Img, and BookmarkedItems. They have relationships between them as follows:

```
ImgThumb <-> Img (1 to 1)
Img <->> BookmarkItems (1 to many)
```

Now, having an ImgThumb Array  I'm trying to make a NSPredicate which filters these ImgThumbs as follows:

- I need all ImgThumbs that are not bookmarked.

In order to achieve this I'm trying to build an NSPredicate using SUBQUERY like this:

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"0 != SUBQUERY(image, $x, 0 != SUBQUERY($x.bookmarkItems, $y, $y.@count == 0).@count).@count"];
```

My Request fails with error:

```
Unable to generate SQL for predicate (0 != SUBQUERY(image, $x, 0 != SUBQUERY($x.bookmarkItems, $y, $y.@count == 0).@count).@count) (problem on RHS)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

You don't need a `SUBQUERY`.  I'm assuming your fetch entity is `ImgThumb`, in which case your predicate should be:

```
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"img.bookmarkItems.@count == 0"];
```